# Opengl terrain height/vertex

Tags: opengl, collision-detection

I have a terrain which is made of triangles lying on xz-plane. Given a x and z coordinate or point, how will I get the y coordinate of that point?

Comment: A triangle lying on a line? What do you mean by `lying on lines x and z`

Comment: @izomorphius I guess he means a regular mesh on a grid in the xz-plane, but you're right in that it isn't explained that well.

Comment: sorry if it was not clear, I don't know what to call it

Comment: What? So you're saying the triangles themselves lie in the xz-plane and don't have any height at all?

Comment: hahaha. Sorry I don't know how to explain it properly. Just forget it, I just asked this question to know how other people do it. I'll just do it my way and hope it will work.

Comment: @markuz So now you're abandoning the question? This really gets better and better.

Answer (score 3):

By doing a barycentric interpolation of the points of the triangle.